Injected contentScript via background.js is not respecting match pattern
Expected behaviour
For injected content script to run on specific pages that I set within my manifest.json
Current behaviour
Contentscript is injected on every page. Or atleast I seem to see errors in console for background indicating background.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access contents of url... ". Maybe it's working but I don't want to see these errors!
Manifest.json – I also tried host_permission as I understand this is relevant permission for programmatic injection
{
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://example-01.au/*",
        "https://example-03.com/*",
        "https://example-02.eu/*"
      ],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus",
    "offscreen",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "tabGroups",
    "storage",
    "scripting",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://example-01.au/*",
    "https://example-03.com/*",
    "https://example-02.eu/*"
  ]
}

Background.js
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((info) => {
  chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, (tab) => {
    if (tab.url?.startsWith('chrome://')) return undefined;
    chrome.scripting
      .executeScript({
        target: { tabId: info.tabId },
        files: ['contentScript.js']
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Scripted Injected');
      });
  });
});

It's not clear from the docs. But, do ineed to programmatically set up page matches within my background.js?

You already inject the content script via manifest.json, so why are you duplicating it in the background script?

I need the contentscript to be injected when a tab changes. This approach actually helps massively. I can remove contentscript reference in manifest.json @woxxom

What specifically do you mean by "tab changes"? Your current listener works when the user switches to another tab.
